# Kannel SMPP Client Queries

Tags: linux, debian, smpp, kannel

I have got a Kannel configuration on Debian platform which is running perfectly fine.

My Query is what is maximum throughput (messages/sec) per connection which kannel supports.

Or

How to increase throughput of Kannel (SMPP server is ready to give me any throughput for my ESME Binding).

Part 2 I want to know what other smpp clients which have high throughput I can use on Debian or windows platform.

I checked some smpp.jar files online but not tried how to use them

My Ultimate goal is to have smpp client should be able to send more messages in a timeslot given.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Kannel, you can increase the throughput using the configuration `throughput` on the `smsc` group in /etc/kannel/kannel.conf (on a default install).  more info in [the docs](http://kannel.org/download/1.4.1/userguide-1.4.1/userguide.html)

You also have the option of increasing the window size (ie. the number of SMS pending submit_sm_resp) using the `max-pending-submits` configuration.  The default for that is 10.

There are lots of options for SMPP libraries.. depending on your language of choice:

- Python - https://github.com/dmaclay/python-smpp
- PHP - https://github.com/onlinecity/php-smpp
- Java - https://code.google.com/p/jsmpp/

All of which can work on debian.  However the problem is that most of what you will find are software *libraries* and you would have to build a client on top of them... so maybe not what you're looking for.

The options for high-quality but low-cost SMPP clients are severely limited in my experience!

Comment: I use kannel regularly & I don't think Kanel have more throughput say max 80. Php Based is good only for sending. Connection doesnt remain binded for ever, so as a smpp client receiving should also be listening for 24*7.  I am pretty intrested in Java Based. But I need to work on its basics first.  Is there any examples of jsmpp ??

Comment: How is your Kannel configured?  What do you have for the two settings above?  Also, php *can* be used to maintain an open, bound connections, check the methods for `enquireLink()`.  As for jsmpp, check the "Getting Started" guide on: https://code.google.com/p/jsmpp/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: Actually I tried using PHP one.. Best for sending.. for Code unbinds the connections once message is sent or recieve.. What I am thinking now is I will use php for TX and kannel for RX